# Windows console application /MT with /ZW

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi

I am trying to build a console application which uses a 3rd party library. I think the third party library is built using /MT and not /MD. The project build and produces an executable but moment I add any STL (like vector, string, ...) the project doesn't build and gives error "error LNK2038: mismatch detected for 'RuntimeLibrary': value 'MT_StaticRelease' doesn't match value 'MD_DynamicRelease".

If Console application project settings is changed to use /MT instead of /MD it build successfully with STL and the 3rd party library.

However, When I enable "Consume Windows Run-time extensions (/Zw)" it says that /MT is incompatible with /ZW"

I don't have access to source code of 3rd party library and can't build it using /MD. and I need to use /ZW in my Console application.

The 3rd party library here is "Intel Media SDK (libmfx.lib)."

Comment: Isn't the source code for the Media SDK dispatcher part of the [Intel Media SDK](https://software.intel.com/en-us/media-sdk) download (see <install-folder>\opensource)?

Comment: I'm not sure why Ajay's answer was downvoted and deleted, but I suspect that his first suggestion may work: to build a wrapper DLL containing `libmfx.lib` and link that with your console application.  You would need to follow all the usual rules for applications with multiple runtime libraries, i.e., make sure the same module that alllocates memory frees it, don't share C filenos between modules, etc.  (IInspectable's suggestion may be better.)

Comment: @IInspectable Thanks I could see the source code and would try to build

Comment: @IInspectable You made my day. Was able to build dispatcher code with /MD